# Only getting name and extension of input type "file" when I get it as array

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms

I am trying something I just learned about which is html form arrays and I am trying that with files now like this

```
<input type="file" name="image_name[]" />
```

When I loop the array in a foreach I see that it only saved the name of the file and extension. Where can I find stuff like its directory?

Foreach loop I perform

```
$image = $_FILES['image_name'];
foreach($image as $oneImage){
  echo $image[0];
}
```

This actually does work

```
$image = $_FILES['image_name'];
foreach($image['tmp_name'] as $oneImage){
  echo $image;
}
```

I need this but without asking for tmp_name in the foreach condition itself.

Also I need to ask for the number 0 instead of 'name'. It's not that much of a problem but is it possible to change that?

Edit:

I just performed a print_r on the foreach array and it gave me this:

```
Array ( [0] => 3.jpg [1] => 5585_387497301371274_1740842451_n.png ) 
Array ( [0] => image/jpeg [1] => image/png ) 
Array ( [0] => /tmp/phpIlm34I [1] => /tmp/phpX7EHX4 ) 
Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 0 ) 
Array ( [0] => 56405 [1] => 504664 )
```

How would I ask for the tmp_name there? Those are from 2 files and let's say I wan't /tmp/phpIlm34I

Answer (score 2):

You will never see the original file directory. Thats the way it is made, mostly for security reasons.

Comment: But I can't ask for $_FILES['image_name']["tmp_name"] for example while I usually could

Comment: It does return something but I don't think its that tmp_name. It returns me 3i/. I noticed that 3 is the first character of the name of the file. This also happens when I ask for [0]['error']

Answer (score 0):

*Where can I find stuff like its directory*?

You can't as there are three things only ([*Reference*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications))

- `name` - The file's name as a read-only string. This is just the file
  name, and does not include any path information.
- `size` - The size of the file in bytes as a read-only 64-bit integer.
- `type` - The MIME type of the file as a read-only string, or "" if the
  type couldn't be determined.

Comment: Then how is it possible to get $_FILES['image_name']['tmp_name'] for example? Im sure that's possible when I don't use an array like that so why shouldn't it when I do?